# Difference between present and gerund of "credere"

Tags: meaning, verbs, difference

What is the difference of meaning between the following sentences?

- Credo in te.
- Sto credendo in te.

Comment: Basically, they mean the same; the first one has a more affermative/peremptory tone; while the second one seems to suggest that the action (of believing) is currently taking place at this moment); the translation difference could be: "I believe in you" / "I am believing in you".

Comment: "I am believing in you" is incorrect English. Stative verbs such as "to believe", "to know", "to doubt", "to wish", "to like", "to prefer", "to sound", "to hear", "to see" and "to taste" are not used in present progressive

Comment: I did not remember that, my fault. Maybe "I am trusting you" could be correct?

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Nope, "to trust" is also a stative verb. In general, verbs which describe thinking/opinion (includes "to believe" and "to trust"), feelings, liking, sensory perception, possession and state are "stative" and are not used in progressive conjugations.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista:  Then, maybe we have the problem of not knowing how to explain in English the very slightly different nuance in meaning of these two sentences.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Does "peremptory tone" in your definition mean "subject to no further debate or dispute" ? What is exactly an "affirmative tone"?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I meant an affirmative, decisive tone

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Let me see if I got this right. So the speaker implies more *certainty* and *confidence* in his/her belief when using "credo in te" than when using "sto credendo in te" ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista it is what I meant :) That could be a matter of personal opinion of course.